# Eclipse plugin for HTML WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm building a small web application in Eclipse. I made an HTML form and was unable to find an option to preview the page I built, and I have to run it on server to view it. In NetBeans, there is a built-in WYSIWYG html editor.

Is there some HTML plugin for Eclipse?

(I don't need MyEclipse)

Answer (score 42):

Since this is currently (2011-10-25) at 2nd place in Google for a "Eclipse HTML WYSIWYG" query and the question linked by Rafa de Castro dont give a complete answer, I feel that this question needs an update.

---

For now, the only available WYSIWYG tools for HTML I found are:

- **[WTP JavaServer Faces](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/main.php)** contains a tool named **Web Page Editor**. Nice, free and also serves as a visual editor.
- **[JBoss Tools HTML Editor](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html)** is also free, neat, has two preview modes, but provides only simplest visual editing functionality.
- **[Eclipse Visual Designer](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html)** shipped with [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/). It can even preview pages in IE/Firefox, but it has a huge disadvantage - it's a paid software. Looks awesome, but I didnt try it, so I can't say anything about quality.
- **[LeetEdit](http://github.com/TimPietrusky/LeetEdit)** is based on TinyMCE and provides enhanced visual editing functionality. It's free and you can fork it on github.

### A note about intsallation.

Installing something into Eclipse is a pain for a new user.

So, if you want to install just an HTML editor from WTP or JBoss without installing the whole thing with it, you can do the following (steps are vadid at least for Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7.):

- Open Eclipse, select `Help / Install New Software`.
- In the `Work with:` field input the update site address.

#### For JBoss Tools:

- Get the update site URL for the appropirate Eclipse version from [here](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html)
- Select `JBoss Tool RichFaces`.

#### For Web Pages Editor

- Use an already existing update site, that look like `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/<eclipse_version_name>`
- Select `Web Pages Editor`.

#### For LeetEdit

- Update-Site `http://timpietrusky.github.com/lab/leetedit/update-site`
- Select `LeetEdit`

Now press `Next` and prepare to wait for eternity. (You can speed up this process by disabling `Contact all update sites during install` checkbox)

Comment: Extra information for everyone visiting here (since my edit was rejected):  
 - I tested all, except "Eclipse Visual Designer". So far, there is much need for more development in these plugins.  They are very slow and non-intuititve to work with (e.g. It's hare to add even simple elements.  Don't expect anything near standalone WYSIWYGs out there! 
 - LeetEdit seems inactive (since 2012-04).
 - Also "Web Page Editor" and JSF is shipped by defualt in Eclipse now. - There is also Bravo JSP, but not much better and on 64bit a lot of installation issues (that can be fixed, but takes time).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the installation of the "Web Page Editor" which is actually called "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor" in the installation menu:

Example for Eclipse Luna (try to use current eclipse version):

- Help => Install new Software => Enter update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
- Go to category "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprice Development"
- Select "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor"
- Also select "JSF Tools" (the icons of the palette wont work if you do not select this)

You can skip the step with the category if you enter "Web Page Editor" in the search box.

The Palette of the Eclipse Luna "JSF Tools -Web Page Editor" does not contain html5 elements.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question when trying to go through some introductory applet exercises that required me to write an HTML file to display the applet I created using Eclipse.  I resolved the issue by using Notepad++  to edit the HTML document, then I stored my HTML file in the bin directory of my Eclipse project.  There is probably a more correct solution, but I was able to get the result that I was looking for: displaying my java applet (created in Eclipse) using a web browser.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully used [richhtml4eclipse](http://www.richclient2.de/richhtml4eclipse/) as the WYSIWYG editor for an internal software project - You get a dialog with native widgets for style buttons, etc, and a plain looking window for the HTML view.

I also applied some post-processing to the output with the Java version of HTML Tidy, but that was more for version-control consistency reasons.

This is a native JFace container with an embedded Browser widget running a page with tiny_mce embedded.

It uses an older version of tiny_mce for it's internal HTML editor, and connects to it via an approach I've seen used elsewhere - passing events out to the native Java app via status bar changes, and accepting input via JavaScript calls on the Browser widget.

Answer (score -1):

aptana studio 3 (eclipse plugin)

Comment: whats next after install?